# OS-X:SWIFTでプログラムを終了させたい。

Tags: swift, macos

Swiftを利用して特定のボタン等のイベントを受け取った時にアプリケーションを終了させたいです。

ご存じの方がいれば、教えて下さい。
宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`NSApplication`クラスの`func terminate(_ sender: AnyObject?)`です。

[NSApplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/terminate:)

Comment: NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
で終了できました。